# How do I Delete something in shape of a picture - Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, layers

[image]

As seen in the image below I have a black circle but I want to delete the middle to be the shape of a square. How would I do this?  I know I can change the color to white, but I want to delete it so it has no background for printing.

This is just an example I would like to do this with a cat silhouette I made.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3):

Select both figures and then go to *Path -> Difference* (<kbd>Ctrl -</kbd>).

This will consume your square, so if you want to keep the square for later, duplicate it first (<kbd>Ctrl D</kbd>).